# How to set current date input value in vuetify 3 labs date picker?

Tags: vue.js, date, datepicker, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

With vuetify 3.3.11 version, I created a date picker component as described from the documentation. But I get the following error when I want to set a date value from the current form as default.

> [Vue warn]: Maximum recursive updates exceeded in component
> . This means you have a reactive effect that is mutating its
> own dependencies and thus recursively triggering itself. Possible
> sources include component template, render function, updated hook or
> watcher source function.

[image]

Here is my codes.

src/plugins/vuetify.js

```
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'
import 'vuetify/styles'
import * as labs from "vuetify/labs/components";
// Translations provided by Vuetify
import { en, tr } from "vuetify/locale";

// Composables
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'

import DateFnsAdapter from '@date-io/date-fns'
import enUS from 'date-fns/locale/en-US'
import trTr from 'date-fns/locale/tr'

// https://vuetifyjs.com/en/introduction/why-vuetify/#feature-guides
export default createVuetify({
  components: {
    ...labs,
  },
  date: {
    adapter: DateFnsAdapter,
    locale: {
      en: enUS,
      tr: trTr,
    },
  },
  locale: {
    locale: "tr",
    fallback: "en",
    messages: { tr, en },
  },
  theme: {
    themes: {
      light: {
        colors: {
          primary: '#1867C0',
          secondary: '#5CBBF6',
        },
      },
    },
  },
})
```

/src/component/DateInput.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-menu
      v-model="menu"
      :close-on-content-click="false"
      :nudge-right="40"
      transition="scale-transition"
      offset-y
      min-width="290px"
    >
      <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
        <v-text-field
          v-bind="props"
          :modelValue="dateFormatted"
          variant="outlined"
          append-inner-icon="mdi-calendar"
        ></v-text-field>
      </template>
      <v-locale-provider locale="tr">
        <v-date-picker
          color="primary"
          :modelValue="getDate"
          @update:modelValue="updateDate"
        ></v-date-picker>
      </v-locale-provider>
    </v-menu>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    /**
     * Date on ISO format to be edited.
     * @model
     */
    value: {
      type: String,
      default() {
        return "2023-10-10"
      },
    },
  },
  watch: {
    value: {
      handler(val) {
        this.input = val;
      },
      immediate: true,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      menu: false,
      input: null,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    dateFormatted() {
      const date = this.input ? new Date(this.input) : new Date();
      let month = 1 + date.getMonth();
      if (month < 10) {
        month = `0${month}`;
      }
      let day = date.getDate();
      if (day < 10) {
        day = `0${day}`;
      }
      return `${date.getFullYear()}-${month}-${day}`;
    },
    getDate() {
      /**
       * Return ISO 8601
       */
      let date = this.input ? new Date(this.input) : new Date();
      return date;
    },
  },
  methods: {
    updateDate(val) {
      // this.menu = false;
      this.input = val
      console.error(val)
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

/src/App.vue

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-row>
      <v-col cols="6">
        <date-input></date-input>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import DateInput from './components/DateInput.vue';

export default {
  components: {
    DateInput,
  }
}
</script>
```

Also, an infinite loop occurs when the update model runs.

[image]

Here is the codesandbox url that you can see it.
https://codesandbox.io/p/github/eguvenc/test/main

Here is the repo that you can test it.
https://github.com/eguvenc/test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a recursive update bug in 3.3.9 - 10 - 12 versions in vuetify date picker.

Vuetify Version: 3.3.9
Vue Version: 3.3.4
Browsers: Chrome 114.0.0.0
OS: Windows 10

Here is the bug link.

https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/17872

A new version was released on Wednesday, August 9, 2023. I installed the new version and everything is fine. It seems fixed.

Answer (score 1):

had the same issue in vuetify@3.3.11

updated to 3.3.15 and it's working